# How to attach pdf file in an email

Tags: android, email, pdf

I want to attach a `pdf` file in an e-mail, I tried this code to send an email containing `pdf` file.

```
String to = textTo.getText().toString();
String subject = textSubject.getText().toString();
String message = textMessage.getText().toString();

Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ to});

email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);             

email.setType("message/rfc822");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this :

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("application/pdf");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "abc@gmail.com" });
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "test " +    test);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "test"); 
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///MyAPP/"+"test.pdf"));
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

After searching around i found this to show how to store files to external memory

[Developers Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory%28java.lang.String%29)

```
createExternalStoragePublicPicture();
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                                    File file = new File(path, "cards_01.pdf");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND ,Uri.parse("mailto:")); // it's not ACTION_SEND
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Card Set ");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(file));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // this will make such that when user returns to your app, your app is displayed, instead of the email app.
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

The link above shows how to delete the files also and says about putting them in correct folders to avoid overwriting other files. Hope this helps any others with same issues

Comment: please accept this as a answer. if it is working. many Thanks.